# Data Parsing firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I plan to retrieval data from Database Firebase to TableView by this code what is wrong with my code and how can i fix it to let all details send to my table view

[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf2Ei.png)
[Run at Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMrR8.png)

And this is my data in the database:
[image: And this is my data in the database]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Ordersv: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var array = [String]()
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var handle: DatabaseHandle!
    @IBOutlet weak  var TableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func add (_ sender: Any){
        if textField.text != ""{
            ref.child("list").childByAutoId().setValue(textField.text)
            textField.text = ""
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak  var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        handle = ref?.ref.child ("Orders/Customer/Detils/").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
                self.array.append(item)
                self.TableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

        self.TableView.delegate = self
        self.TableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong wit the code:

1. You never initialize `ref`.
2. When you observe `.value`, you get multiple nodes back. Your code doesn't handle this fact.

To fix both, I recommend:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
handle = ref.child("Orders/Customer/Detils/").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let name = value?["Name"] as? String ?? ""

    self.array.append(name)
    self.TableView.reloadData()
})
```

The above code observes the `.childAdded` event, which fires immediately for each existing child node, and then once for every subsequent child that is added.

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive than that? If you run the code in the debugger, does it trigger the `childAdded` closure? Does it go into the `if` block? I updated the code to better reflect your data structure, but that is mostly copy/paste from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: when i run  its work but not the child  i will edit my question and see the new picture

Comment: i added new picture that will explain  i need the data in  Name,Phone,Address 1, Address 2